# «Проснуться не в срок»

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, лексическая-сочетаемость

Можно ли использовать сочетание "в срок" в следующем выражении ("не в срок" в значении "не в запланированный момент")?

*Я сегодня проснулся не в срок, и опоздал на работу.*

Answer (score 1):

Для начала убираем ненужную запятую перед союзом "и" (он соединяет однородные сказуемые *проснулся* и *опоздал*):
**Я сегодня проснулся не в срок и опоздал на работу.**

Затем рассматриваем значения слова [**срок**](http://www.endic.ru/kuzhecov/Srok-49718.html):
2. Назначенный, установленный момент исполнения, наступления чего-либо.
**В срок**, в значении *наречия*. Вовремя.

Потом знакомимся с [синонимами](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-6129.htm) "в срок" (ведь все подходящие значения невозможно указать в словарной статье):
в положенный срок, ко времени, час в час, к сроку, своевременно, минута в минуту, в урочный час, в положенное время, без опоздания, вовремя.

В словаре Ефремовой:
**в сро́к**, *наречие*. Точно тогда, когда назначено; вовремя.

Думаю, что в разговорной или поэтической речи, в переписке между друзьями такое использование вполне возможно.

Будимир находил себя не худо, шел своими лапами, но к просьбам спутников прокукарекать **не в срок** и тем вызвать спасительный дождь пребывал глух. [Михаил Успенский. Там, где нас нет (1995)]

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя (во всяком случае, для объяснительной записки это не подходит), выражения со словом *срок* употребимы только в отношении **дней** и **дат** (*срок* столько-то дней или *срок* до такого-то числа такого-то месяца). В данном случае: "**я вовремя не проснулся**" (сочетание "*не вовремя*" обычно означает "в неподходящий, неблагоприятный момент"); в общем случае: *не сделать (что-то нужное) вовремя*.

Answer (score 0):

Можно/нельзя, ну кто ж вам может запретить...

[Yulia Balabanova](https://vk.com/note3220860_9963147?reply=27840590):
4 Aug 2010

> ТУМАН
>
> Мой дом-теплоход плывет по туману,
>
> И города нет. Лишь синий туман.
>
> По спящей реке, на юг, к океану
>
> Плывут в тишине большие дома.
>
> Уходят дома. В них спят пассажиры,
>
> В предутренних снах теряя покой.
>
> Наполнил туман каюты-квартиры,
>
> Ни звука, ни зги – над спящей рекой.
>
> **Проснуться не в срок**, и в сумраке окон
>
> Увидеть: вокруг молочная тьма,
>
> И между миров, легко, одиноко
>
> По небу плывут большие дома.
>
> 04.08.2010

Comment: Ох уж эти женские поэтические вольности :)

Сквозь вакуум мчась, я проснулся не в срок:
Сферический конь мой в беспамятстве лёг.

Comment: @Alex_ander - вообще-то в стихе это выглядит весьма органично (само стихо не оцениваю). Лирический герой ко сну относится чуть ли не как к работе, которую надо сдать по дед-лайну. Это трудно объяснить формализровано, но здесь замена на "не вовремя" обедняла бы не только ассоциативный ряд, но и смысл вообще.